# Pharo Cog Spur Virtual Machine has stopped working, restore a broken image

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

When I try to launch a Pharo Image that I have been working on, Pharo opens, but then immediately crashes.

Can anyone help me figure out how to either:

1. save my image?
2. save the code in my image to copy to a new image?
3. dig in and investigate this further?

When I open my image, it now crashes and shows the following crash message:

[Pharo Cog Spur Virtual Machine has stopped working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8XF0.png)

In the details, I get the problem signature:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Pharo.exe
  Application Version:  5.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_e5fb
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: PCH_94
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: e5fb
  Additional Information 2: e5fbb79501a5ec44936c965495b7ed9d
  Additional Information 3: 87e1
  Additional Information 4: 87e19eaa5875c71ec8875aadb1c1eca7
```

I am launching my Image from "Pharo Launcher version: 2.2".

My image was created from the template: `Image template (Pharo 8.0 - 64bit (stable))`

In my image I loaded *Roassal3* from `github://ObjectProfile/Roassal3:v0.9.5`

I tried copying my image, and opening the copy, but same result (as expected I guess).

I had a look at `PharDebug.log`, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. This is a copy of by [PhaorDebug.log](https://pastebin.com/uWfE8PSy).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started to answer in comment then it got too long for it.

It is always best to save your work to `CVS` like `merucrial` or `git`.  Pharo has a facility called `iceberg` for git.  I would recommend pushing your changes instead of relying on the image.  You have to then recover the file using the `*.changes` file.

Also it would be helpful to see the `PharoDebug.log`.  You can share it with us via `pastebin.com` or similar.

If the Cogs VM crashes on you you have to go to a `.changes` file which should have the same name as your image file.

### For example:

For image `Pharo8.0-command_line.image`, you will find your changes in `Pharo8.0-command_line.changes` file.

### To recover your code:

1. Backup your changes file
2. Download a fresh new image
3. Run Pharo with new image
4. Drag the `.changes` file into Pharo
5. Use Change browser to pick up the code you want to recover.

### Report the bug:

You should report the bug at [Bug report for Pharo](https://pharo.org/contribute-report-bug).

Comment: Thank you @tukan. I have updated the question to include a link to my PharoDebug.log. I did use Iceberg on this project, but wasn't sure how up to date it was. Your solution to drag the .changes file into Pharo worked well. Thank you.

Comment: @Dave78 Glad to be of help.  I recommend pushing the changes as often as you can to avoid such scenario.  Pharo's VM is currently rather unstable.